# About the Fréchet derivative of this functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\psi:C[0, 1]\to \mathbb R$ be defined by
$$
\psi(f) = \int^{1}_{0} f (t)^2 dt.
$$
I know that in this case
$$D_{\psi, f}(g) = 2\int^{1}_{0}f(t)g(t)dt,\quad \forall g \in C[0 ,1].$$

If we define $S = \{ f \in C[0, 1]: f(0) = 1\}$ and $\psi|_S: S \to \mathbb R$ defined the same way as above, why in this case
$$D_{\psi|_S, f}(g) = 2\int^{1}_{0}f(t)g(t)dt,\quad \forall g \in \text{span}(S-f)?$$

Comment: Why would it be any different???

Comment: It reminds me as how derivative of a smooth function $f$ on a manifold $M$ (embedded in some $\mathbb{R}^N$ is define at some point $x\in M$ in Guillemin-Polack's differential topology. Extend $f$ (locally) to some open neighborhood of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and define $f'(x)$ as $F'(x)$ restricted to $T_x(X)$. It is a simple exercise to show that $f'(x)$ is well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but $S$ is not a vector space (maybe you meant to write $f(0) = 0$ instead of $f(0)=1$?), so the Frechet derivative isn't well defined in the usual sense. Nonetheless, you can still define the pathwise derivative along paths that remain in $S$. For example, if $f \in S$ and $g \in C[0,1]$ satisfies $g(0)=0$ then $f+\varepsilon g \in S$ for all $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$. We can define $T_f S$ to be the tangent space at $f$ which consists of all such functions $g \in  C[0,1]$ with $g(0)=0$. Thus, it makes sense to define the derivative along such paths:
$$d\psi_f|_S(g):= \frac{d}{d\varepsilon} \psi|_S(f + \varepsilon g) \Big |_{\varepsilon =0} =  \frac{d}{d\varepsilon} \psi(f + \varepsilon g) \Big |_{\varepsilon =0}  = 2 \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)dt.$$
It is straightforward to show that $d\psi_f|_S$ is a bounded linear operator on the tangent space $T_f S$, so that $\psi$ is pathwise differentiable. This notion of pathwise differentiability generalizes Frechet differentiability to function spaces that are only normed vector spaces in a local sense (e.g. convex spaces). I believe the technical term for such spaces is Frechet manifolds.

Also, it should be clear that $T_f S = \text{span}(S- f)$ so this agrees with what you wrote.

$T_f S$ consists of all directions that stay in the space $S$. We are ignoring the fact that $S$ is embedded in the larger space $C[0,1]$. We do this because we are interested in intrinsic properties of the space $S$ (which is a well-defined space/geometry/manifold without mentioned the ambient space $C[0,1]$). When you restrict a functional to the space $S$, you are not allowed to talk about the ambient space as the restricted functional is not defined on it. For example, suppose $f \in S$ and $g \in C[0,1]$ is arbitrary and such that $f + \varepsilon g $ is **not** in $S$ for any $\varepsilon\neq 0$. Take for example, the constant function $g(x) :=1$. $\psi_f |_S$ is only defined on $S$, so the "derivative",
$$\frac{d}{d\varepsilon} \psi_f |_S (f + \varepsilon g ) = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\psi_f |_S (f + \varepsilon g ) - \psi_f |_S (f)}{\varepsilon}$$
is totally not defined, as the above evaluations are not defined. Obviously, if we replace $\psi_f |_S$ with $\psi_f$ then the above is well-defined. But, the point is that we cannot do this as we care about the restriction $\psi_f |_S$.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I haven't studied tangent spaces yet, so I'm trying to understand it with just span($S-f$). If I got you right, $span(S-f)$ includes all the directions in which we could define a derivative? If so, how can this be?

Comment: You have to be very precise about where all the functionals/operators are defined. This might seem pedantic but this has important consequences (e.g. in statistics, the efficient influence function changes when tangent space changes)

Comment: Also, if $g \in span(S-f)$ then $f+\varepsilon g$ is in $S$ which is the domain of $psi_f |_S$. Thus, we can evaluate its derivative along this path. This is analogous to defining a function on the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not defining it on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The derivative only makes sense along paths contained in the sphere (which are in the direction of the tangent vectors of the sphere).

Comment: Also, in general, for other spaces, $g \in T_f S$ does not imply $f + \varepsilon g \in S$ . This only needs to hold in first order. For example a straight line tangent to the sphere is not contained on the sphere but one can construct a line that is contained on the sphere that has the same tangent vector as this straight line at the point of intersection.